# What's the weapon in the co-op missions Drop 'em like liquid and Exfiltration?

Tags: battlefield-3

What's the weapon in the co-op missions "Drop 'em like liquid" and "Exfiltration" of Battlefield 3? Can it be unlocked and used in multiplayer mode?

As far as I can recall, it's a powerful automatic marksman rifle with magnified night-vision sights. The only IRNV sights that I can find as unlocks for multiplayer are those of the MK 11 MOD 0 and SVD rifles, but are not magnified. Also, these rifles are semi-auto.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The weapon you start with in Drop 'Em Like Liquid is a silenced Mk11 with a bipod. The scope on the weapon is a special attachment as it can only be found in single player and in co-op. While there is an IRNV scope in multiplayer, it has no magnification (it is 1x), probably for balancing purposes.

In Exfiltration, the weapon I think you're talking about is actually an assault rifle (the [G3A3](http://battlefield.wikia.com/wiki/G3#Battlefield_3)) with an IRNV scope (the one found in multiplayer).

The multiplayer IRNV scope can be unlocked with most primary weapons by performing 100 kills (which incidentally also awards a service star for the weapon). The G3A3 can be unlocked by getting 160,000 points in co-op (it's the last weapon to be unlocked).

Comment: Thank you. So, basically, the magnified IRNV in Drop 'Em Like Liquid cannot be obtained in multiplayer, if I understand correctly. What about the IRNV for the G3A3? Is it magnified?

Comment: @CesarGon No, it's not. It's essentially a reflex sight with IR capabilities, with the added twist that you have to hold your breath to steady your aim (again, probably for balancing reasons).